# Is it mandatory to have a link to the theme designer?

Tags: themes

I just wanted to know if it's ok to modify/remove links pointing to the designer of the theme.

In my case I have "theme by" and the site's logotype, would it be ok to remove the logotype and write the site's name? Or remove it altoghether?

Does it have to do with the particular designer of the theme?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the license under which the Theme is released.

Assuming the Theme was released under GPL: no; you are free to change the Theme in any way you want. If you redistribute the Theme, modified or unmodified, you are required to maintain the original copyright/license information *in the Theme file headers*, but are still not required to have a public-facing attribution or link.

If the Theme was released under CC-By: no; you are free to change the Theme in any way you want. As with GPL, you are required to maintain the original copyright/license information *in the Theme file headers*, including a link to the Theme's license information, but are still not required to have public-facing attribution or an arbitrary public-facing link.

If the Theme was released under any other license, you'll need to consult the terms of the applicable license.

Comment: Did I read that right under CC-By I thought you had to have a public-facing attribution.

Comment: No, CC-By most certainly does **not require a public-facing link**. [From the legalese](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/legalcode): *keep intact all copyright notices for the Work and provide, reasonable to the medium or means You are utilizing...* The **reasonable to the medium** for a PHP work would be a PHP file-header attribution, NOT a public-facing link.

Comment: And also (note: emphasis added): *to the extent reasonably practicable, the URI, if any, that Licensor specifies to be associated with the Work, **unless such URI does not refer to the copyright notice or licensing information for the Work**;* The link MUST refer to the **license information**, not an arbitrary credit link.

Comment: good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

See discussions  [**here**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147385/is-it-ok-to-remove-theme-credits-from-footer) and [**here**](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-it-okay-to-remover-copyright-footer/).

p.s. If you are using **LITE** version of PREMIUM THEME, or downloaded theme from not Wordpress Repositoy, then it is questionable. You'd better ask the developer.